# How to get JSON response into a ListView in .NET Maui?

Tags: c#, json.net, maui

I'm a beginner with .net maui and know just enough about programming in general to get myself super confused and frustrated.  I'm hoping someone can help me out with getting some code I've been working on for a couple of days to the next step.  I want to get the results of the JSON data into a ListView on the Page:

```
namespace App.Models
{
    public class Posts
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("title")] public string Title { get; }
        [JsonPropertyName("body")] public string Body { get; }
        [JsonPropertyName("type")] public string Type { get; }
        [JsonPropertyName("username")] public string Username { get; }
        [JsonPropertyName("communityName")] public string CommunityName { get; }
        [JsonPropertyName("noComments")] public string NoComments { get; }
    }
}
```

I don't yet have anything in a ViewModel yet, so this is what I have in MainPage.xaml.cs for now:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using App.Models;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace App;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<Posts> PostCollection { get; set; }
 
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public class RestService
    {
        HttpClient _client;

        public RestService()
        {
            _client = new HttpClient();
        }

        public static async Task<List<Posts>> GetPostData()
        {
            var url = $"https://myapi/posts";
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
            var successCode = await client.GetAsync(url);

            //validate connection
            if (successCode.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Code 200 -  Successful Connection to REST API");

                JObject root = JObject.Parse(response);

                //Get JSON results into a list
                List<JToken> results = root["posts"].Children().ToList();
                //BindingContext = this;

                //PostCollection = new ObservableCollection<Posts>();

                int count = 0;
                while (count < 10)
                {
                    //create variables for data needed
                    string postType = (string)root["posts"][count]["type"];
                    string postUsername = (string)root["posts"][count]["username"];
                    string postCommunityName = (string)root["posts"][count]["communityName"];
                    string postTitle = (string)root["posts"][count]["title"];
                    string postBody = (string)root["posts"][count]["body"];
                    string postNoComments = (string)root["posts"][count]["noComments"];

                    Console.WriteLine(postTitle);
                    if (postBody != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(postBody);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(postType);
                    Console.WriteLine(postUsername);
                    Console.WriteLine(postCommunityName);
                    Console.WriteLine(postNoComments);

                    //PostCollection.Add(new Posts { Title = postTitle, Body = postBody });

                    count++;
                }
    return null;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error connecting to API");
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    async private void GetJSON_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await RestService.GetPostData();
    }

}
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App.MainPage"
             Title="MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding FinalResults}">
            <ListView.Header>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Button x:Name="responseButton" VerticalOptions="Center" IsEnabled="True" Text="Get JSON response" Clicked="GetJSON_Clicked" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ListView.Header>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell Text="{Binding Title}" Detail="{Binding Body}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            
        </ListView>
        
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Any pointers on where I go next and/or what I'm doing wrong so far?

Thanks!!

I've tried multiple variations of trying to get the JSON data into a ListView, but they all failed.

EDIT:

So, going through this advice I'm afraid I haven't made much progress.  I've got 3 .net maui books opened to the REST API/JSON Parsing parts and the official .net maui documentation open and none of them seem to have a complete working example of how this should work or notes about what I should be looking for, lol.

Looking at postResults it looks just like the JSON to me, except without the root "posts" level anymore.  I don't know if this is the format that ListView wants or not, but nothing seems to happen if I try to bing postResults to it.  Looking at FinalResults I just get "App.Models.Posts[]", same result of nothing happening when I bind it to ListView and press the Get JSON response button in the app (other than the Console.WriteLines showing the data as expected, just not sure what the correct format I'm looking for is.

The documentation says "A ListView is populated with data by setting its ItemsSource property to any collection that implements IEnumerable." but I'm not really sure what that would be.

EDIT 2: Removed OnAppearing() code - focusing on getting the button working right first. Updated rest of code to match where I'm at now.

Thanks so much for your patience with a beginner/learner!!

Comment: there is a LOT to unpack here.  To start with 1) `GetPostData` will **always** return `null`.  You never actually return the data you get from the service and place in `postResults`.  2) even if you did return data, you are not doing anything with it in `OnAppearing`.  You need to assign it to something that you can then set as the `ItemsSource` of your `ListView`

Comment: Ah okay, got ya - I'll stop trying to get a return value out of that function :)  I'm going to edit the code to try to show what I'm doing now with attempting to assign it to something (also not working for me).

So, omitting that, how do I get RestService.GetPostData(); to run before the page loads, I assume that needs to happen or there won't be any values for the ListView to use?

Comment: * With breakpoints/stepping through code, find out what step isn’t doing what is expected. Examine root, results, FinalResults. If OnAppearing seems to be part of problem, or makes debugging harder, test on a button click, until it works there. Then try again in OnAppearing. * Personally, I design apps to start on a simple LoadingPage (Logo + Loading… or whatever), then do potentially slow work on a background thread (Task.Run). Then when data is ready, change back to MainThread, and go to the page that needs the data. Thus, UI is never waiting for data - it always shows something.

Comment: I would focus on getting it to work with a button first.  Once that is working, then focus on making it work with OnAppearing

Comment: You need to use the override keyword in OnAppearing